# Error después de validación

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Resulta que estoy intentando realizar la validación de un formulario por jquery y después que a través de ajax haga unas comprobaciones en otra pagina .php, pero no llega a entrar, realiza las validaciones y se sale a la pagina de inicio.

Codigo del Javascript:

```
<script src=»https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js» type=»text/javascript»></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('#myform').validate();
            $('#alta').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var numero= $('#numero').val();
                var año= $('#año').val();
                var nombre= $('#nombre').val();
                var tipo_caso= $('#tipo_caso').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "crearasunto.php",
                    data: {"numero": numero, "año": año, "nombre": nombre, "tipo_caso": tipo_caso},
                    success: function(respuesta) {
                        $('#mensajes').html(respuesta);
                    }
                })
            });
});
</script>
```

Y el código PHP del formulario:

```
<body>
<header>
                        <h2>Nuevo Caso</h2>                     
                    </header>
<form method="post" id="myform">
                            Dar de alta un caso <br><br>

                                    <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" required pattern="\d*" placeholder="Caso" />
<select name="año" id="año" onchange="escribir(this.value);">
                                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                        <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                        <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                        <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                        <option value="2020" selected>2020</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre operación">
<?php   
                                //cargo la lista de tipos de caso 

                                echo "<div class='col-4 col-12-mobilep'>    <select name='tipo_caso' id='tipo_caso'>";
                                $resultado = mysqli_query($link, "select * FROM tipo_caso");
                                $contador=0;
                                while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
                                        if ($contador==0) {
                                            echo "<option value='$col_value'>";
                                            $contador++;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo " ".$col_value."</option>";
                                            $contador=0;
                                        }          
                                    }
                                }
                                echo "</select>";                               
                            ?>  
    <span id="mensajes" style="color:#FF0000;"></span>
    <li><input type="submit" id="alta" value="Alta Caso" /></li>    
    <li><input type="button" onclick="location.href='inicio.php';" value="Volver"><br></li>                         
</body>
</html>
```

Lo único que se me ocurre es que después de validar no se pueda realizar otra función. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta... ¿El segundo código es el archivo `crearasunto.php` o qué es? ¿Qué quieres decir con que *se sale a la página de inicio*?

Comment: ¿Qué hace la función `$('#myform').validate()`? Si verifica que toda la información esté correcta y devuelve verdadero o falso, entonces debería estar dentro de la función click del botón y ejecutar AJAX solo si la validación fue correcta.